# How to delete a subscription to a useless calendar on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

iOS 7.1.2 → 9.3.1

I think I added a subscription to a calendar through:

```
Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Add Account > Other
         > Add Subscribed Calendar
```

(This is the case for a calendar about national holidays, and for Birthdays. 
I am convinced I added it because I searched this function for a
long time. But I have no track of the origin of this subscription,
either within the configuration of `Calendar` on iPhone, or within any
Apple technical documentation.
Then this subscription might also be a magic one (based on configuration,
or actual position).

I know how to hide this subscribed calendar.

Now I would like to remove this subscription. I don't want to waste network trafic and storage for information I don't use (I already have this calendar on my Mac).

I searched if there wasn't any trick with complex finger manipulations around this subscription entry within:

```
Calendar > Calendars > Edit
```

- throw it on the right
- throw it on the left
- throw it upward
- throw it downward
- long click
- very long click

Nothing! This function might be better hidden, in too deep a labyrinth or beyond my reach. But I can't understand why it has to be hidden like
this.

What is the way to delete a subscribed
(or coming automatically with iOS version) calendar on iPhone?

Comment: Usually you remove it the same way you added it. So, you go to `Settings` > `Mail, Contacts & Calendars`, tap on your subscribed calendar account and tap remove at the bottom.

Comment: I don't have a remove at the bottom. Perhaps this subscription is set by default. Anyway I don't have any documentation or information to confirm this hypothesis.

Comment: If you added it yourself, you will have a remove button. I know that one subscribed calendar is added by default (at least with iOS 9, though you state you have 7.1.2), which cannot be removed and that is the vacation calendar of the country you set up. For me, it is US Holidays. The only thing you can do there is to disable it.